# [user-name]@git.drupal.org: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: version-control, community-official-site

I am trying to use git.drupal.org without success...

- I have uploaded my public key in the `SSH keys`tab under my profile
- I have checked that the fingerprint on Drupal match my fingerprint in
  `.ssh/id_rsa`
- I have Filled in the `Git access` tab under my profile=> I got a username and I accepted the agreement

But when I run: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv -p 22 -i /home/myname/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" git clone my_user_name@git.drupal.org:project/a_project.git`

I got the following error: `my_user_name@git.drupal.org: Permission denied (publickey).`

Here is the output: (to anonymize the following, I replaced my Git user name by "my_user_name" and my computer User name by "myname")

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "git.drupal.org" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to git.drupal.org [140.211.10.58] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myname/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/myname/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Ubuntu-10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to git.drupal.org:22 as 'my_user_name'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/dev/null"
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:FeJiekFTTnXWc1GDUfFVcRckyZkZfdmks1dSqtS6OVg
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/dev/null"
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/dev/null"
Warning: Permanently added 'git.drupal.org,140.211.10.58' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key myname@mycomputer - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/myname/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:J9ZRdKhvB9rfq/uchczwpi2CyvOqzktf9q+12AIetxE explicit agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/myname/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:J9ZRdKhvB9rfq/uchczwpi2CyvOqzktf9q+12AIetxE explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
my_user_name@git.drupal.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Any hint?

`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cloning a project as maintainer of that project is done using the following command.

```
git clone git@git.drupal.org:project/a_project.git
```

The username is always *git*.

As non-maintainer, the command to clone the project is the following.

```
git clone https://git.drupalcode.org/project/a_project.git
```

When I want to clone one of the projects hosted on drupal.org for which I am maintainer, I use the following command.

```
git clone drupal:project/a_project.git
```

In the .ssh/config file, I added the following lines.

```
Host drupal
   HostName git.drupal.org
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_drupal
```

In this way, the Git command is using the correct identity file, even if I have multiple identity files (for example, one for GitHub and one for Gitlab).

The Git command I reported to clone a project, as maintainer or not, is what the *Version control* tab of every project (for example https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/git-instructions for Drupal, where you won't see the instructions for maintainers, if you aren't one of them).
What reported in [Generating SSH keys (Linux)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1066928) is outdated. [Git Authentication for Drupal.org Projects](https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/user-accounts/git-authentication-for-drupalorg-projects#s-cloning-or-authenticating-over-https) has the most updated information. In particular, under [Changing Git Remotes](https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/user-accounts/git-authentication-for-drupalorg-projects#s-changing-git-remotes), it says:

> If you are a maintainer who has an established Git remote in the format `<username>@git.drupal.org:project/<yourproject>.git`, the format should be changed to `git@git.drupal.org:project/<yourproject>.git`.

Comment: Thank you, there are useful information in your answer. I was knowing the fact that we could use "git" as user name, but my goal was to use my user name as explained in: https://www.drupal.org/node/1066928 (under Test your Key) : `git clone [git-username]@git.drupal.org:project/examples.git` If you confirm that I must not use my user-name to clone, I will validate your answer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno is correct and is telling you the current way to access git repositories on git.drupalcode.org. The documentation page at  drupal.org/node/1066928 is very outdated - the method it describes was changed about 9 months ago and is no longer correct.

Comment: Yes, that page needs to be updated. There must be a page reporting the changes in authenticating on the Drupal.org Git server.